# Lotus Notes 9.01: Mac vs. PC client & Input Enabled

Tags: lotus-notes, osx-yosemite

This is all in the Notes standard client, 9.0.1 (FP3 on Mac). I've got a dialog. The **Product** field is a dialog list; the **Recheck** field is a checkbox. A list of up-to the last 50 records of Product is refreshed and shown in single-select listbox field **ParentIssue** upon changing the Product field. If both Product and Recheck are not "", I enable input for ParentIssue, so the user can select one from the list.

This works as expected in the Windows client (Win7 Pro), but not in the Mac client. In the Mac client (Yosemite), selecting a product works, as does the lookup to fill the ParentIssue options. However, checking the Recheck checkbox does not enable ParentIssue, and in fact stops the ability of the user to either change Product or uncheck Recheck. Fortunately, the OK and Cancel actions still work.

Even if only a few options in ParentIssue the dialog is broken. However, if there are *no* options for ParentIssue, the user can change Product even with Recheck checked, and Recheck can be toggled correctly.

Can someone duplicate, or know of a bug report or fix? I've had no luck finding any info.Thanks.

Comment: This is a programming website.

Comment: InputEnabled is an event that his code is supposed to handle, so this question is releated to programming.

Comment: Get fp4 ASAP fp3 on the Mac is broken.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about fp4, but still same behavior.